# Is there a way for linux to display caller id?

Tags: modem, telephony

After switching to linux, one thing i miss is something called phonetray, which displayed caller ID to my screen. I wondered if there is a way for Linux to do something similar.

I found a blog discussing NCID and call blocking [here](https://murphy101blog.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/raspberry-pi-telephone-number-blocker/).

Is there a way to use NCID and have the caller ID display for a brief time on screen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

[linux-caller-id](https://code.google.com/archive/p/linux-caller-id/) listens to what's coming from a modem on the landline receiving the call. It requires the installation of libQtCore4 and libQtGui4, a la `sudo apt-get install libQtCore4 libQtGui4` before it can be added to your system.

If you are receiving calls on a cellphone, you can add [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/) to numerous browsers (Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, and Opera) to get an onscreen pop-up with the caller ID data. And, if you have an Android phone, you can add an app on it to [block identified spammeristas](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mistergroup.shouldianswer), which has worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of [Raspberry Pi Telephone Number Blocker -- Murphy 101 Blog](https://murphy101blog.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/raspberry-pi-telephone-number-blocker/) that you link to is quite old. The software in that article is [NCID - Network Caller ID](http://ncid.sourceforge.net/) and continues to be updated. It will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

was able to make linux-caller-id function in Mint 19.1 by adding libqtcore4:i386 and libqtgui4:i386 in addition to libqtcore4 and libqtgui4. Don't forget to make the downloaded file executable in properties/permissions

Answer (score -1):

I found the below linux-caller-id and if it worked it would be perfect for my needs. But, it doesn't work under Mint 19, and there's no make in the source. Sigh.